# this activity is crashing as soon as i open it. String variable which is globally declared is not getting assigned by any new value

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

> I was trying to fetch some data from firebase and this is one of the activity of my project.This activity is crashing as soon as it opens.
> Data fetching is good is we pass reference directly on to child(),but when we try to pass any String variable- which is assigned from a editText- throwing problem. Here what I have found is that the studentBranch variable is getting assigned a new value from the " studentYear=(String) yearSelect.getText().toString()" method but it is not passed onto the firebase reference child().
> help me to fix this !, I'm completely a noob in android development

```
    package com.example.presence;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class viewStudentsDetails_Activity extends AppCompatActivity{
    RecyclerView recView;
    Button fetch;
    EditText branchSelect,yearSelect;
    viewStudentAdapter myadapter;
    public  String studentBranch;
    public String studentYear;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_students_details);
        recView=findViewById(R.id.recView);
        fetch=findViewById(R.id.buttonFetch);
        branchSelect=findViewById(R.id.editTextDepartment);
        yearSelect=findViewById(R.id.editTextYear);
        recView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        fetch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                studentYear=(String) yearSelect.getText().toString();
                studentBranch=(String) branchSelect.getText().toString();
                //reference=database.getReference().;
                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<viewStudelModelclass> options =
                        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<viewStudelModelclass>()
                                .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("students").child(studentBranch).child(studentYear), viewStudelModelclass.class)
                                .build();
                myadapter=new viewStudentAdapter(options);
                recView.setAdapter(myadapter);
            }
        });


         DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration=new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(),DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
         recView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        myadapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        myadapter.stopListening();
    }




}
```

> here is my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".viewStudentsDetails_Activity"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Department"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.141"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.045" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.921"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextDepartment"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="eg: ME"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.859"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.028" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Year"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.141"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.137" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextYear"
        android:layout_width="126dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="eg: 2016"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.859"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.138" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonFetch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fetch Details"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.248" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You are talking about code in onClick handler. But this code is not executed at opening activity. Better post the relevant lines from the logcat.

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this article, [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).